# Asp.Net MVC : application startup - user request relation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, startup, lifetime

I came into the point where I have to manage lifetime of the dependencies. These dependencies opens a connections to different databases. And are registered to Unity container. The unity container register components during application startup.

I'd like to know when does application startup happen? Is it in every user request?

I much appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Application_Start()` in `Global.asax.cs` is executed only once in the application life cycle and not during each request.

If you want to initialize something for the entire application but not for the request alone, then this might be helpful. But if you're looking to allocate and deallocate for each request, then you might need to do it somewhere in the controller.

Comment: @Wao : If you have further doubts, feel free to revert.